# How to insert an image in canvas and after that insert text in this canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to insert an image in a canvas and after that I want to insert an input text in the same canvas, but I can't do it. How can I fix this problem?

Now, I want that the user insert a draggable text in the actual canvas. The people say that  using [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) is easy, but I can't get it working:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvasThumbResult");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("target");
context.drawImage(img, getX, getY, getWidth, getHeight, 0, 0, 238.11023622,332.598425197);
```

Comment: can we see some code to be able to assist better?

Answer (score 4):

**Here is how to add user-specified text on an image and allow the text to be dragged**

[image]

This solution uses a canvas library called [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) and jQuery to simplify the task.

Here’s how it works:

- Create the Kinetic Stage (this activates the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) canvas)
- Create a new image object in [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) (this loads your image into an object)
- Create a new Kinetic Image object and put your new image in the Kinetic Image object
- When the user types text in the input and hits the “Add” button…
- Create a new Kinetic Label object using the user’s text
- To make the new text label draggable, just set `draggable:true` when creating the object

Here’s the code that makes it all work…

**Create the Kinetic Stage (this activates the HTML canvas)**

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 300,
    height: 300
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);
```

**Create a new image object in JavaScript (this loads your image into an object)**

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){

        // Your image is fully loaded, so…

        // Create your kinetic image object here

    layer.add(image1);
    layer.draw();
}
image.src="koolaidman.png";
```

**Create a new Kinetic Image object  and put your new image in the Kinetic Image object**

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){
    var image1 = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        image: image,
    });
    layer.add(image1);
    layer.draw();
}
image.src = "koolaidman.png";
```

**When the user types text in the input and hits the “Add” button…**

```
<input id="newtext" type="text" value="Hello!">
<button id="addbutton">Add this text</button>

$("#addbutton").click(function(){

    // Create your new kinetic text label here

});
```

**Create a new Kinetic Label object using the user’s text**

```
$("#addbutton").click(function(){

      // Simple label
      var label = new Kinetic.Label({
          x: 20,
          y: 20,
          draggable:true
      });

      label.add(new Kinetic.Tag({
          fill: 'green'
      }));

      label.add(new Kinetic.Text({
          text: $("#newtext").val(),
          fontFamily: 'Verdana',
          fontSize: 18,
          padding: 10,
          fill: 'white'
      }));

      layer.add(label);
      layer.draw();
});
```

**To make the new text label draggable, just set `draggable:true` when creating the object**

```
// Snipped from the kinetic label creation above

var label = new Kinetic.Label({
    x: 20,
    y: 20,

    // Set draggable:true to make the kinetic label draggable
    draggable:true
});
```

You can download the Kinetic library and learn more with examples in *[HTML5 Canvas KineticJS Label Tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-label-tutorial/)*. You can download the jQuery library and learn more with examples here at the [jQuery home page](http://jquery.com/). jQuery is a great library for eliminating cross-browser inconsistencies.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/pQYz9/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Prototype</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #container{
              border:solid 1px #ccc;
              margin-top: 10px;
              width:300px;
              height:300px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#addbutton").click(function(){
                      // Simple label
                      var label = new Kinetic.Label({
                          x: 20,
                          y: 20,
                          draggable:true
                      });

                      label.add(new Kinetic.Tag({
                          fill: 'green'
                      }));

                      label.add(new Kinetic.Text({
                          text: $("#newtext").val(),
                          fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                          fontSize: 18,
                          padding: 10,
                          fill: 'white'
                      }));

                      layer.add(label);
                      layer.draw();
                });
            }); // End $(function(){});
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="newtext" type="text" value="Hello!">
        <button id="addbutton">Add this text</button>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The HTML at the end is not [well-formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element) - there isn't any end tag for `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Should it be `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`?

Comment: and now if I want to save the image, how can do it??

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999879/kinetics-saving-image-error/19009949#19009949

Comment: @markE - If instead of adding text on top of the image I wanted to add a poligon (or any shape, suppose a circle) would there be much of a difference? In particular I'm thinking of answering this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984834/draw-on-top-of-an-image-using-javascript) using fabric (or anything other library). Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

**Using Scrawl.js:**

(Disclaimer: I am the developer of this library)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Scrawl.js</title>
        <style>
            body {margin: 1em;}
            img {position: fixed; visibility: hidden;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol>
            <li>Display an image in a canvas</li>
            <li>Add text to canvas</li>
            <li>Drag text around canvas</li>
            <li>Change text via an input box</li>
        </ol>
        <div>Change text by typing in this box: <input type="text" id="changetext" value="Hello world" /></div>
        <img src="img/penguin02.jpg" id="penguin" class="demo903" />
        <canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <script src="js/scrawl.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){

                //import the image and create a sprite to display it
                scrawl.getImagesByClass('demo903');
                scrawl.newPicture({ 
                    source: 'penguin',
                    width: 400,
                    height: 400,
                    });

                //construct a sprite to display the text
                //and a group for collision detection stuff
                var texts = scrawl.newGroup({
                    name: 'texts',
                    });
                var displayText = scrawl.newPhrase({
                    font: '24pt bold Arial, sans-serif',
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    textBaseline: 'middle',
                    startX: 200,
                    startY: 200,
                    fillStyle: 'yellow',
                    strokeStyle: 'black',
                    shadowColor: 'black',
                    shadowBlur: 8,
                    method: 'fillDraw',
                    text: 'Hello world',
                    group: 'texts',
                    });

                //add event listeners to handle text drag-and-drop
                var here, myText;
                var getText = function(){
                    myText = texts.getSpriteAt(here);
                    if(myText){
                        myText.pickupSprite(here);
                        }
                    };
                var dropText = function(){
                    if(myText){
                        myText.dropSprite();
                        myText = false;
                        }
                    };
                scrawl.canvas.mycanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', getText);
                scrawl.canvas.mycanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dropText);

                //add event listener for changing the text
                var input = document.getElementById('changetext');
                var updateText = function(e){
                    displayText.set({
                        text: input.value,
                        });
                    };
                input.addEventListener('keyup', updateText);

                //build an animation loop for updating the canvas
                var myPad = scrawl.pad.mycanvas;
                var animate = function(){
                    here = myPad.getMouse();
                    //drop the text if mouse moves out of the canvas area
                    if(!here.active && myText){
                        dropText();
                        }
                    scrawl.render()
                    requestAnimFrame(function(){
                        animate();
                        });
                    };
                //start animation
                animate();
                };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Working demo: [over at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KaliedaRik/VWFhb/)