# Kinetics saving image error

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, kineticjs

Im having problems with kinetics. I have a stage with kinetics with a one image and text, but that I want is export the stage to a image like myImage.jpg no like [data:image/wIlksoks.e] that it is the callback that return dataUrl() from kinetics.

Im trying with this code:

```
stage.toDataURL({
    width: 350,
    height: 350,
    mimeType: "image/jpeg",
    callback: function(dataUrl) {
      /*
       * here you can do anything you like with the data url.
       * In this tutorial we'll just open the url with the browser
       * so that you can see the result as an image
       */
      window.open(dataUrl);
    }
  });
}, false);
```

King Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can use stage.toDataURL to get your dataURL for the server:

```
        stage.toDataURL({
            callback:function(dataURL){

                // dataURL is available for saving to your server

            }
        });
```

**Note: Be sure that your image and your .html are hosted on the same domain.**

*Otherwise your stage.toImage will fail because of CORS security.*

So be sure to check your console for CORS security errors !

**Alternatively:**

You can use stage.toImage to create a dataURL  from your image+text.

Then you can create a temp canvas to get the dataURL.

```
stage.toImage({
    callback:function(stageImg){

        var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
        var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
        tempCanvas.width=stageImg.width;
        tempCanvas.height=stageImg.height;
        tempCtx.drawImage(stageImg,0,0);
        var dataURL=tempCanvas.toDataURL();

        // dataURL is available for saving to your server
    }
});
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/RV694/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.0.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        start();
    }
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/KoolAidMan.png";

    function start(){

        var kImage = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            image:img
        });
        layer.add(kImage);

        var kText = new Kinetic.Text({
            x:20,
            y:20,
            fontSize:24,
            fill:"blue",
            text:"Hello!"
        });
        layer.add(kText);

        layer.draw();

    }


    $("#stageAsImage").click(function(){

        stage.toImage({
            callback:function(stageImg){

                var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
                var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
                tempCanvas.width=stageImg.width;
                tempCanvas.height=stageImg.height;
                tempCtx.drawImage(stageImg,0,0);
                var dataURL=tempCanvas.toDataURL();
                var imageElement=document.getElementById("newImage");
                imageElement.src=dataURL;

            }
        });

    });


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <button id="stageAsImage">Save stage as image</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <img id="newImage">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the same result, I cant see any diference...really I need to save like as image because I need to send to File Transfer to upload the image to the server!

Comment: Ok...I see...but You know why I cant send the image to File Transfer to upload the image in my server? I think that I need to save this image in my gallery or something similar because File Transfer is working when I take a picture or from gallery because the file that send to File tranfers is like "sd/mm/picture" . do you mean?

Comment: Ohh...sorry King King Thanks!! Im so gratefully!

Comment: Hi...one thing...for some reason the code is not working in the device...with these, dont do anything!

Comment: stage.toImage({
            callback:function(stageImg){

                var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
                var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
                tempCanvas.width=stageImg.width;
                tempCanvas.height=stageImg.height;
                tempCtx.drawImage(stageImg,0,0);
                var dataURL=tempCanvas.toDataURL();
                var imageElement=document.getElementById("newImage");
                imageElement.src=dataURL;

            }

Comment: Quite curious! It works for me...Have you checked the console for CORS security violations?

Comment: markE I check all the function...and is working fine in Ripple but when I want to use in Phonegap, the device dont do anything!!

Comment: markE, I have othe problem, do you know how can put limit to the dragable area in the image canvas with the text?

Comment: Sure, you can limit the dragable area for any shape or group by specifying its custom dragFunc.  The dragFunc executes *before the object is actually moved each time* and it has a pos.x and pos.y which will be where the object will be moved next.  If you don't want the object to move to that new pos.x/pos.y you can just change the x/y to whatever limited area you desire.  Cheers!  Here's a link to the dragFunc: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-shapes-horizontally-or-vertically-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks markE, and do you know why is not working the save image with   stage.toImage({
            callback:function(stageImg){

            } Is working fine in Ripple but not in phonegap!